# Android Forground sevice stops when the app is closed

Tags: android, kotlin, service, background-service

I am starting a background service which receives data in the background, so for this, I have used android foreground service, the service works perfectly in some mobiles (MI A2 Stock Android), but in some mobiles when I remove the application from background tray the service gets destroyed.

```
class MyService : Service() {
    private val CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundService"

    companion object {
        fun stopService(context: Context) {
            val stopIntent = Intent(context, MyService::class.java)
            context.stopService(stopIntent)
        }
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        // I get some data from intent 
        // My code which runs in the background

        createNotificationChannel()
        val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0
        )

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("App is syncing")
            .setContentText("")
            .setPriority(2)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()
        startForeground(190, notification)
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID, "Foreground Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            manager!!.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
        }
    }
}
```

This how I start the service

```
val serviceIntent = Intent(this, MyService::class.java)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(serviceIntent)
        } else {
            startService(serviceIntent)
        }
```

So my question is how can I make my service running even when the APP is removed from the background tray.

Answer (score 0):

**Do these things**

> 1) Restart the service when app is closed by overriding this method in
>   your service class , copy and paste this

```
override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
    val restartServiceIntent = Intent(applicationContext, this.javaClass)
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(packageName)
    val restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
        applicationContext,
        1,
        restartServiceIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
    )
    val alarmService =
        applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    alarmService[AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000] =
        restartServicePendingIntent
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
}
```

> 2) Change this `START_NOT_STICKY` to `START_STICKY`
>
> 3) Ask user to enable autorun permission from settings , this feature
>   is provided in custom os like mini devices, vivo,huawei and oppo etc.
>
> 4) and you forgot to restart the service on device boot up like you
>   need to use a broadcast receiver to restart service when the device
>   restarts

Comment: still facing the same issue.

Comment: to run the service continously app kill you have to restart the service , no other option

Comment: so perform the steps which i mentioned

Comment: I have followed the 1 & 2 steps. what is 3rd step & I hope 4th step is optional

Comment: 3 step - go to settings and enable autorun in those devices where service is stopping